# Unable To Retrieve Selected Image Url To Display - Firebase / Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collectionview and wanted to let users click on an image which takes them to another view controller with that image but larger. The issue is that the image is not loading on the new view controller. I am not sure on what the issue is. If someone could help me out I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Variable images:

```
var images = [UserImages]()
```

didSelectItemAt collectionview:

```
 func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
             
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
        
        vc?.name = images[indexPath.row] // Issue: 'Cannot assign value of type 'UserImages' to type 'String'
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
```

DetailViewController:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    var name = ""
    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/Images/\("name")")
        
        loadDB()

    }
    
    func loadDB() {
        
       dbRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            var newImages = [UserImages]()
            
            for UserImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                
                let UserImagesObject = UserImages(snapshot: UserImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
                newImages.append(UserImagesObject)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.img.image = UIImage(named: self.name)
            }
            
        })
        
        
    }

}
```

UserImages (used to pull imageURL from firebase realtime database)

```
struct UserImages {
    
    let key: String!
    let url: String!
    
    let itemsRef: DatabaseReference!
    
    init (url:String, key:String) {
        
        self.key = key
        self.url = url
        self.itemsRef = nil
        
    }
    
    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        
        key = snapshot.key
        itemsRef = snapshot.ref
        
        url = snapshot.value as? String
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
vc?.name = images[indexPath.row].url
```

and load the image from server with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)